# See Everything In The Terminal/Command Prompt After Long Output

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I'm new to ubuntu using the terminal to code some ruby.

Everytime I run this command it outputs like 600 lines of data that I need to analyze.

But when I try to scroll up to see everything alot of the output is cut off.

Is there any way to change the settings of the terminal or another command prompt program or any other options that I can use to take a look all of the data?

Comment: A good alternative is to output it directly to a file, then view the file in a text editor: `someCommand > someFile.txt`.  See more here: https://askubuntu.com/a/420983/327339

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Inside your Terminal Window, go to `Edit | Profile Preferences`, click on the `Scrolling` tab, and check the `Unlimited` checkbox underneath the `Scrollback XXX lines` row.  Click `Close` and be happy.

Comment: But this only works for the next time you want to run your command. Is there a way to view the last command which produced output way above? Is there a shell history option?

Comment: If you have had scrollback long enough to overflow your current buffer settings, and then you later change the buffer scrollback settings, there is no way to retrieve output that you had previously not configured your Terminal to remember.  The only way to get that information would be to re-run the command.

Comment: Thanks. Was trying the accomplish the same with `awk[#\[[€␡⌦sed<<pr|atg}}\ -n1 patate++|| && slip 4 | head 0` but i had some syntax errors

Answer (score 21):

Run the command with

```
> command | less
```

It will only show you as many lines as it can fit on the screen, and then you can scroll down to read the rest.

Answer (score 11):

I agree with Tudor: "piping" the terminal output into the program `less` is an effective way to do what you want.  To see a list of available actions in `less` press `h`.  A particularly useful command is `/` to search the text in less.  Note that `q` quits the program.

Another option would be to use a stdout redirection operator `>`. So for example you could also run your command as:

```
$command > output.txt
```

Then the output of your terminal will be written to the file output.txt which could then be opened with any text editor.  Note if you use `>>` instead of `>` the output will be appended to the end of the text file instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 9):

Shift + PageUp
Shift + PageDown

Answer (score 4):

If you use iTerm2 then you can select the `Unlimited scrollback` under `Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal`

Answer (score 4):

I use iTerms and the version is Build 3.3.6.

Select `Unlimited Scrollback`

`Preference` -> `Profile` -> `Default` -> `Terminal Tab` -> `Scrollback Buffer` -> `Unlimited Scrollback`

[image: iTerms Preferences screenshot]

Comment: I concur with this answer for those who use iTerm. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this response comes much later, but I was googling for an answer today to this issue, and I changed my profile settings in my iTerm2 in the Terminal tab to unlimited scroll, and it did not work. Then, when I ran the command `npm rebuild > ~/desktop/output.txt`, I noticed the following warning at the end out the output:

```
npm rebuild > ~/desktop/output.txt
info sharp Using existing vendored libvips v8.8.1
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found 
(target=11.14.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be 
removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be 
removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be 
removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
✔ mozjpeg pre-build test passed successfully
✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
✔ cwebp pre-build test passed successfully
(node:94642) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory 
leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() 
to increase limit
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
```

So it's definitely better to simply redirect the output from a command to a txt file and not worry about memory leaks! Just thought I would share. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**`tmux` and GNU `screen`**

Sooner or later, you will give in to those awesome tools:

- `tmux`: https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux
- `screen`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40242/scroll-inside-screen-or-pause-output/40243

Answer (score 1):

You can also view it in vim directly.

```
 command | vim -
```

Answer (score 1):

run "command > output.txt;less output.txt" ';' seperates each command, command one means:
write the output of the command to output.txt
command two means:
show the content of output.txt

I'm not using the ';' to explain, if you paste the whole command(including the ';') in your terminal, it will actually run.

Answer (score 0):

In my Xubuntu terminal I can use the spacebar to advance the output, "b" to go back, and "q" to quit to the prompt.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).